# Drupal 6 Apache Solr Search Problems with result ordering & fields

Tags: 6, search

As I am implementing a website made in Drupal 6 and using Apache Solr search as the search application in the website.

Drupal Version 6.22
Apache Solr Version : 3.6
Apache Solr Module: 6.1.x

Below are the two problems I am facing.

1. While searching a particular content the business requirement is to search only in the Title field, Body field and in the Terms attached in a node. How can I achieve that?
   I have used the HOOK_apachesolr_modify_query() in some other purposes. Do I have to mention all the filters here again? like,

```
mymodule_apachesolr_modify_query(&$query, &$params, $caller) {
   $query->add_filter('title', $keyword);
   $params['fl'] = 'title';
}
```

1. The second is that once the contents are being searched as per the requirement I should get the result based on the following algorithm.

1st result = (Match in Title + Match in Body + Match in Terms names) (Keyword present in all)

2nd result = (Match in Title + Match in Terms names) (Keyword only present in title & term names)

3rd result = (Match in Title + Match in Body) (Keyword present in Title & Body)

So I added a boost factor from the Apache Solr admin section as 
Title = 1.0
Term = 0.50
Body = 0.25

But the ordering is not maintained.

I even also mentioned

```
function mymodule_apachesolr_modify_query(&$query, &$params, $caller) {
   $params['qf'] = array('taxonomy_names^0.50', 'title^1.00', 'body^0.25');
}
```

But no effect. Please suggest any ideas.
Help me on these issues, I am really stuck here :(

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you look into the Views module and/or [Apache Solr Views](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views). This blog post http://blog.hsl.virginia.edu/drupalpress/apachesolr-views-drupal-6/ might also be useful.

Comment: Hello, 
I suppose the link you shared is only for Views 3.x branch and same goes for Apache Solr as well.
Quoted in the Website as 
"Note to all: we’re using views 3.x-dev, apachesolr 3.x-dev, and apachesolr_views 3.x-dev."
Please have a good look at my requirements. thanks.